# Disable clicking in one mapbox layer, when the other is visible

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

There are two layers in a mapbox map inside a react app. I am new to both. I want to disable clicking in one layer, when the other is visible. I control the visibility of each layer from a checkbox value via react.

I have this code

```
export default function Map () {   
  const [checkedLayer, setCheckedLayer] = useState(true);
  const [checkedOtherLayer, setCheckedOtherLayer] = useState(true);

  //when a checkbox is on or off make layer visible or not
  const handleVisibility = (event) => { 
    let visible ; let layer;  
    event.target.checked ? visible = 'visible' : visible = 'none'
    
    if (event.target.id === 'mylayer') { 
      setCheckedLayer(event.target.checked);   
      layer = 'mylayer';
    } 

    if (event.target.id === 'myotherlayer') { 
      setCheckedOtherLayer(event.target.checked);   
      layer = 'myotherlayer';
    } 

    map.current.setLayoutProperty(layer, 'visibility', visible); 
  }; 

useEffect(() => { 
  if (map.current) return; // initialize map only once  
   map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: mapContainer.current, 
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11',
    center: [lng, lat],
    zoom: zoom
  });//map  

  map.current.on('load', () => { 
     //...set layers and sources 
  });//load 

  map.current.on('click', 'mylayer', (e) => {
    console.log('other layer visibility ', map.current.getLayoutProperty('myotherlayer', 'visibility'));
   // I want to do something like 
   // if map.current.getLayoutProperty('myotherlayer', 'visibility')) == 'visible' 
   // return
   // but the above console.log keeps giving "undefined"
   // map.current.getLayoutProperty('mylayer', 'visibility') works
  }); 
     },[checkedLayer, checkedOtherLayer]);//useEffect 

  return (
    <div> 
              <Checkbox
                id="mylayer"
                checked={checkedLayer}
                onChange={handleVisibility}
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
              />
              <Checkbox
                id="myotherlayer"
                checked={checkedOtherLayer}
                onChange={handleVisibility}
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
              />
      <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container"> </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When `mylayer` is clicked I try to check the value of the visibility of `myotherlayer` and  if it is `visible`, return, so nothing is executed inside `'click', 'mylayer'` function. But the value of `map.current.getLayoutProperty('myotherlayer', 'visibility'));` is `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to add codesandbox?

Comment: How is this code running? Can you provide code that is complete, functional, testable?